# SQL | How to compare two tables with same structure

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the same struture, T_1 = [A, B, C] T_2 = [A, B, C]. There are differences between them in values inside. How can I get these values using a query ?

Regards

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: [ANSI SQL](https://www.quora.com/What-is-ANSI-SQL-Oracle-SQL-and-MySQL) defines the INTERSECT operator which allows you to find the common rows between two database tables. What you want is the opposite of INTERSECT. The SQL query required to achieve this depends on the DBMS you are using. So if you want a truly relevant answer that provides you with actual SQL code that you can use, you need [edit] your question and add the relevant tag for the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and aggregation to get values that are in one table and not the other:

```
select sum(in_1), sum(in_2), a, b, c
from ((select 1 as in_1, 0 as in_2, a, b, c
       from t_1
      ) union all
      (select 0, 1, a, b, c
       from t_2
      )
     ) tt
group by a, b, c
having sum(in_1) <> sum(in_2);
```

Note that this is quite generic.  It handles `NULL` values in the columns.  It also handles duplicates within the tables, ensuring that the counts are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an easy way of coding but is not good enough in performance

```
(select * from T_1
 minus
 select * from T_2)
union all
( 
 select * from T_2
 minus
 select * from T_1
) ;
```

If you are looking for another way , and I recommend that check this 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_set_to_join_sql_parameter.htm

Comment: `EXCEPT` is ANSI SQL for what Oracle has MINUS.

Comment: I think MINUS also is supported by all SQL products providers, correct me please if I’m wrong.

Comment: Perhaps some, but certainly not all.

Comment: SQL Server implements `MINUS` as `EXCEPT`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TABLE1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TABLE2